# What are the requirements to take the private pilot check ride?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, logging

In the US, what are the requirements that a student pilot must demonstrate to their examiner  before they can take a checkride for their private pilot airplane certificate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Private Pilot Airplane Single-Engine Checkride Requirements

### Eligibility Requirements ([14 CFR 61.103](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c9181abc36bfecf4684a3a110a7f0f6a&node=14:2.0.1.1.2.5.1.2&rgn=div8))

- Be at least 17 years of age for a rating in other than a glider or balloon
- Be able to read, speak, write, and understand the English language
- Instructor logbook endorsement certifying your aeronautical knowledge ([14 CFR 61.105](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c9181abc36bfecf4684a3a110a7f0f6a&node=14:2.0.1.1.2.5.1.3&rgn=div8)) and that you are prepared for the written test
- Passed the written test and can present your original embossed Airman Knowledge Test Report
- Instructor logbook endorsement certifying your flight proficiency ([14 CFR 61.107](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c9181abc36bfecf4684a3a110a7f0f6a&node=14:2.0.1.1.2.5.1.4&rgn=div8))and that you are ready for the flight test
- Log all required aeronautical experience (below)

### Aeronautical Experience ([14 CFR 61.109](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c9181abc36bfecf4684a3a110a7f0f6a&node=14:2.0.1.1.2.5.1.5&rgn=div8)):

- 40 hours of flight time (35 for 141 schools) that includes:

  - 20 hours of dual instruction
  - 10 hours of solo flight training
- 3 hours of cross-country dual
- 3 hours of night dual (to get an unrestricted license) that includes:

  - 1 cross-country flight of over 100 nautical miles total distance
  - 10 takeoffs and 10 landings to a full stop (with each landing involving a flight in the traffic pattern) at an airport
- 3 hours of instrument dual
- 3 hours of dual in preparation for the practical test within 2 calendar months
- 10 hours of solo including

  - 5 hours of cross-country time
  - 1 150 NM solo cross country flight, with full-stop landings at three points and one segment of the flight consisting of a straight-line distance of more than 50 NM between the takeoff and landing locations
  - 3 takeoffs and 3 landings to a full stop (with each landing involving a flight in the traffic pattern) at an airport with an operating control tower

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure someone will post the exact regs, but as a stop-gap, from memory:

- 40 hours (35 if the school is part 141) minimum total time
- 20 hours dual instruction
- 3 hours flight "by reference to instruments" (under the hood)
- 5 hours solo cross country (50nm minimum between two points along each trip)
- One solo 150nm XC flight with at least 3 airports (two of which must be at least 50nm apart)
- 3 hours night flight (dual instruction)
- One night XC (dual)
- 10 night landings (full stop)
- 3 hours of dual instruction explicitly for check ride prep, within 90 days of the check ride
- Endorsements for the items above needing endorsements
- An endorsement from a CFI stating the candidate is prepared for the check ride.

Additionally, mine has a statement that my (part 61) CFI had seen my US passport (and its number) establishing proof that I am a US citizen, in accordance with 49 CFR 1552.3(A).

Comment: This was pretty close for being from memory!

Answer (score 2):

Mah explained everything very well.

The non-flying requirements are:

- Be at least 17 years old (14 years old for glider or balloon rating)
- Be able to read, speak, write and understand the English language
- Obtain at least a third class medical certificate from an Aviation Medical Examiner
- Pass a paper/computerized aeronautical knowledge test
- Pass an oral test and flight test administered by an FAA inspector, FAA-designated examiner, or authorized check instructor

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_certification_in_the_United_States#Private_pilot)

Answer (score 0):

Regulations are somewhat different for different aircraft (airplane, helicopter, glider, etc). I'll assume the question asks about private pilot for single-engine land-based aircraft (SEL).

For the United States, answer can be found in FAR §61 subpart E. Applicable sections are: 103(a),(c)-(j), 105, 107(a),(b)(1), 109(a).

Reference: [FAR §61, Subpart E](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=1e34acc0646cdf8bf39113d9728a7a4a&node=14:2.0.1.1.2.5&rgn=div6)

Disclaimer: not a lawyer, just a humble student pilot navigating this gauntlet himself :-).

Comment: You may want to include the relevant requirements in your answer. As it stands currently this would be considered a [link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), because in the (unlikely) event ECFR's link layout changes folks would have to go Google the FARs rather than having the information available to them here.