# Sport pilot upgrade to private pilot

Tags: faa-regulations, ppl, checkride

I have a sport pilot license and fly my own SLSA (Special Light Sport Aircraft). I have all the required logbook hours signed off by my CFI for the PPL and 120 hours as PIC plus 80 dual student hours. Once I pass the PPL written test and obtain a 3rd class medical, would I be required to take a full oral test and check ride to obtain a PPL?

Notes:

- SLSA: Special Light Sport Aircraft
- CFI:  Certificated Flight Instructor
- PIC:  Pilot In Command
- PPL:  Private Pilot License

EDIT: Thanks for responding. I do have 3 night flying hours + 3 hours under the hood. I did all the required private pilot flying and ground school hours before deciding to go the light sport route. I'm thinking about about getting the private pilot license if and when the 3rd class medical is eliminated as a requirement. So, my question is - what would I be tested on for the private pilot checkride? Or would a checkride even be required?

Comment: which legislation are we speaking about?

Comment: Is this in the US (FAA)?

Comment: PPL requirements are mentioned here: [What are the requirements to take the private pilot check ride?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1199/65)

Comment: It sounds like you have almost all of the training for your PPL done.  You will just have to make sure you have a valid FAA medical, and then take the written exam, as well as the checkride.  Having a PPL is definitely an improvement over a sport!

Comment: By the way, pilots are "certificated", not certified.

Comment: Yes.  As you are seeking a new grade of pilot certificate, you will have to conform to the requirements under 61.103.

Answer (score 5):

I believe PPL also requires some night flying time (at least the 141 school I am at does). I believe Sport Pilot License is not valid at night so you may have to gain some night landings and hours to go for the check ride as well. However I do see that you have all the hours signed off so I will assume this includes night hours.

But AFAIK you will need to pass the written, oral and check ride to get the PPL.

As per your updates [this](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/FAA-S-8081-14B.pdf) is what you will be checked on for your check ride. Its a bit dated but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kr483zBbQKw) video has some nice coverage on what you may get on your oral exam. If you have the Jeppesen study materials you should have some good lists of what you will find. I did find this in the FAR

> §61.103   Eligibility requirements: General.
>   To be eligible for a private pilot certificate, a person must:
>
> (a) Be at least 17 years of age for a rating in other than a glider or balloon.
>
> (b) Be at least 16 years of age for a rating in a glider or balloon.
>
> (c) Be able to read, speak, write, and understand the English language. If the applicant is unable to meet one of these requirements due to medical reasons, then the Administrator may place such operating limitations on that applicant's pilot certificate as are necessary for the safe operation of the aircraft.
>
> (d) Receive a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor who:
>
> (1) Conducted the training or reviewed the person's home study on the aeronautical knowledge areas listed in §61.105(b) of this part that apply to the aircraft rating sought; and
>
> (2) Certified that the person is prepared for the required knowledge test.
>
> (e) Pass the required knowledge test on the aeronautical knowledge areas listed in §61.105(b) of this part.
>
> (f) Receive flight training and a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor who:
>
> (1) Conducted the training in the areas of operation listed in §61.107(b) of this part that apply to the aircraft rating sought; and
>
> (2) Certified that the person is prepared for the required practical test.
>
> (g) Meet the aeronautical experience requirements of this part that apply to the aircraft rating sought before applying for the practical test.
>
> (h) Pass a practical test on the areas of operation listed in §61.107(b) of this part that apply to the aircraft rating sought.
>
> (i) Comply with the appropriate sections of this part that apply to the aircraft category and class rating sought.
>
> (j) Hold a U.S. student pilot certificate, sport pilot certificate, or recreational pilot certificate.

In regards to section H you have to pass the practical for the PPL specifically so it would seem you will be retested. Although part J would allude to the fact that your SPC comes in here it seems that it just counts in place of a student pilot certificate.

Comment: What jurisdiction is this please?

Comment: United States FAA

Comment: @Simon, since the question was tagged "FAA regulations," I think it is clear that this answer applies to the USA.

Comment: @SpongeBob Ah, missed the tag.  Sorry.

Comment: @Simon, it actually looks like your comment was posted before the tag was added.  So it's my bad for being sassy.  It just seems like people ask that question very often when it usually doesn't need to be asked.

Comment: @SpongeBob when speaking of regulations is instead critical to ask that question, since regulations can be wildly different depending on the authority making them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no reduction in the examination requirements to go from a Sport Pilot to Private Pilot. You will need to take the written, oral, and practical tests as if you just held a Student Pilot certificate. The [Practical Test Standards](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/FAA-S-8081-14B.pdf) for Private Pilot include a table which can reduce the maneuvers you need to demonstrate on the practical test based on certificates already held - but they all require a Private Pilot or higher.

All of your solo/PIC hours as a Sport Pilot count for the requirements for the Private Pilot certificate, as do any dual time with a CFI or CFII. Any dual time with someone who only has a CFIS (Sport Pilot instructor) certificate does not qualify as experience for the Private Pilot certificate.

The full requirements for you to take the Private Pilot practical test are available in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1199/65).